# RSA verification always return success even if wrong public key provided in python

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa, signature

I encounted one strange question about rsa signature and verification. Any help is appreciated.

I signed data using Crypto package with rsa private key, while verifying the signature, it never throw exceptions even if the wrong public key was specified. The Crypto version is 3.12.0 and python is with 3.8.

```
Python 3.8.8 (default, Nov 11 2021, 21:29:06)
>>> Crypto.__version__
>>> '3.12.0'
>>> Crypto.__path__
>>> ['/home/desktop/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/Crypto']
```

Code as follows, and the output are "True True True True"(If I change LINE 71 and 72 to "return verifier.verify(hash, signature)", it will print "False False False False". But, the last one should be True, isn't it???)

```python
import base64
import traceback

from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5

PRI_KEY = '''-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'''

PUB_KEY = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA2TS4aH0JCS6odJkVqNTh
DPKB0HigozOstxliFSmSaJvLIanY/TNhiEhJfhLe1fTaqNKbY5AJEKHvUooDCd/u
vUgtEXVcYSIu/+yCsonRu/rxpDDPr/vtIN0xgvNFJjKWZkNX3sIEecqsdSA4BwYq
hTTC59NJhLyw1Cq1zUy8BufnHOrnN4pNGq9rdSE6TXj12ffxt7zKGrgUy8tKcfyP
2svsoKnQ7nf3n7frYt1zNtm5lbjID6UWPHRjOOwMBSsG9z2mvbyqQVX6ZlE9r66O
Hu8h9fMCgII2XJdWQAn4VbEPw344tI2c+h5eZsa1tw8SbEQsAaEaDSPvSXZEioDF
7wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''

def verify_signature(data: bytes, signature: bytes, pub_key: str) -> bool:
    """验证签名是否正确"""

    if not data or not signature:
        return False
    key = RSA.importKey(pub_key)
    hash = SHA256.new(data)
    verifier = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
    try:
        verifier.verify(hash, signature)  # LINE 71
        return True                       # LINE 72
    except ValueError:
        print (traceback.format_exc())
        return False

def sign_data(data: bytes, pri_key: str) -> bytes:
    """对字节数据进行RSA签名，返回str类型"""

    if not data:
        return b""
    key = RSA.importKey(pri_key)
    hash = SHA256.new(data)
    signer = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
    signature = signer.sign(hash)
    return base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature)

def test4():
    data= b'abcdefg'
    signature = sign_data(data, PRI_KEY)
    pub_key1 = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAr71sVzl5CsJnw9lRX/Ja
ACH7UpqqnhjqJTkeCEgPOJx2ob1Adv4oGDz1CgSecoXfGYSOOB04iiWLUAZ3wShQ
1t9UzjvQpfIIevSBL321NEts6r/IGjcKVcxqyFpffodV2CBav0Kd/SHD4Ht36HnU
4yyL36v7wPOEby4pxtnbFsk5UhraObQ6b7WgWLzCZ0m/UBpYl32uQODLO9LHnbgr
c6bjawjQfw2TVKkryr1mmjOrt/N/sWidBLmiXPCEyhCz/EiWcYG8v57b7PXiTN1c
CcUHzwqLLC1Oy+1YlYfY9GK4XdU+BaxOD9yN+DUDGAUY5c/4lUvEcD78CXJq2E+1
RwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
'''

    pub_key2 = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsQpsGPBuZ5FfOP5hRQf0
vtBUi+y6qsGP+SkLnd8Rji+1yz+ezUqJBkX1T5v952ZeR8XVaDZw6+zgBv2Lhoc3
jt6u4LDH0YF5cbBinoDeCH/03vS1AkuVjGKDuculrGPpc1/e8FAPe+KhyxCnHsjO
1bPCS3OxFtfG/4gnzzBw+19mX/7lGQSz2ugY6NQ6+f1miamuZMhyWQsnuGCnA9Qd
FeZRCKvJTwYzS/mgAq3tzc6qENkn9POMHJBj/Jd0iOmGFYMjg/hqkWjWExm2SGz1
ynJpetOxw44AWQAfOvWBh30FaCb9URHUoVi8jXN9gmN5V6ofK7UPsZKaLLzvhnCa
owIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    '''
    pub_key3 = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsQpsGPBuZ5FfOP5hRQf9
vtBUi+y6qsGP+SkLnd8Rji+1yz+ezUqJBkX1T5v952ZeR8XVaDZw6+zgBv2Lhoc5
jt6u4LDH0YF5cbBinoDeCH/03vS1AkuVjGKDuculrGPpc1/e8FAPe+KhyxCnHsj2
1bPCS3OxFtfG/4gnzzBw+20mX/7lGQSz2ugY6NQ6+f1m1amuZMhyWQsnuGCnA9Qe
FeZRCKvJTwYzS/mgAq3tzc6qENkn9POMHJBj/Jd0iOmGFYMjg/hqkWjWExm2SGzz
ynJpetOxw44AWQAfOvWBh30FaCb9URHUoVi8jXN9gmN5V6ofK7UPsZKaLLzvhnmd
owIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
    '''
    for pub_key in (pub_key1, pub_key2, pub_key3, PUB_KEY):
        print( verify_signature(data, signature, pub_key))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test4()
```

Comment: I know the reason now, before verifying signature, the signature should be base64 decoded

Comment: Even with this (correct) fix the code doesn't work because a wrong module is used. `Crypto.Signature.PKCS1_v1_5` is deprecated and returns the verification result as _return value_, so it doesn't throw an _exception_ in case of an invalid signature. It is intended for backward compatibility with legacy PyCrypto and shouldn't be applied beyond that. Instead, use [`Crypto.Signature.pkcs1_15`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/signature/pkcs1_v1_5.html), which throws an exception for an invalid signature.